# Xamarin.Forms 2017 TTS, no error but TTS is happening

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, text-to-speech, nuget-package

Trying to get a simple button to play a simple string in using TTS in Xamarin.

Some methods we have tried are

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/text-to-speech/#Creating_the_Interface
- https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-7-Plugins-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

The second one is as follows, after adding the plugin to the project and the Android and iOS levels.

```
    using System;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Plugin.TextToSpeech;

    namespace AppOne
    {
       public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
       {
           public MainPage()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void btnHelp_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak("Help");
           }    
       }
    }
```

Break point was used to check to see if the line was ever run, it was.

Will this method not work with 2017 and we have to use 2015?

We also are using "Live Player" for testing, could that be an issue?

We have used multiple devices including LG G3, SAMSUNG S2 tablet, and a couple other Andriod devices of friends.

Comment: I would not expect this to work on LivePlayer.  Test on a device or emulator instead

Comment: confirmed it worked when I made it an apk, why doesn't it work on live viewer? Will there be other things that I would expect the same result?

Comment: LivePlayer is not a full blown emulator.  It is intended primarily for previewing UI.